# In a C*-algebra, pure states which share the same kernel are equal

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I'm reading C*-Algebras by Jacques Dixmier. And in the proof of 2.9.5, it says

> Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. If $f$ and $f'$ are two pure states which
>   have the same kernel, then $f=f'$.

It should be obvious I guess, but I cannot understand why. It would be very helpful if anyone can give me some hint.

Comment: And also, it would be much appreciated if someone could recommend me any recent good books about C*-algebras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with pure, not even with positivity. States extend uniquely to the unitization of $A$, so we may assume that $A$ is unital .

Let $x\in A$. Then $x-f(x)I\in \ker f=\ker f'$. Then 
$$
0=f'(x-f(x)I)=f'(x)-f(x). 
$$
So all we are using is linearity and that $f(I)=f'(I)=1$. For two arbitrary functional we the same kernel, we would obtain $f'=c\,f$ for some constant $c$.

As for books, the canonical sources are Murphy's book, and Davidson's *C$^*$-algebras by Example.*

Comment: Somehow I always hesitate before I assume a C*-algebra is unital. Thanks for saving me from struggling in this trivial fact.

Comment: By the way, have you by any chance read this Dixmier's book? Do you think it's classic or maybe too old-fashioned to read?

Comment: It's a classic, in a sense, but it is too old in my view. I would stick to some of the newer texts.